# Can a single processor have varying frequencies for each core?

Tags: architecture, cpu, processor, cpu-architecture

I was reading a blog post about a company that sells Bitcoin mining hardware. Their specialty is the use of ASIC to achieve highest possible (energy) efficiency. I have few questions that are not specifically related to bitcoin mining. Would anyone please answer!

1. Is it possible/practical to make a processor consisting of several cores, where each core has different frequency (or generally, different manufacturing processes 20nm, 14 nm etc, or different performance features)?
2. Can different cores of CISC, RISC & ASIC be grouped inside a single processor?

Answer (score 3):

**1.**
First of all related to your first question:
It is very difficult to produce processors which are produced by different production processes. Processors (and chips in general) are 'printed' on wafers, many processors together on the same wafer. They are not fabricated in parts and put together afterwards. So in general only one manufacturing process is used per processor.

EDIT: "I have to add however, that a processor consists of many layers (20 or more), some layers can be more critical than others (detail is more important), for this layers another production process can be used. But its still applied to the whole die (printed processor), so to all the cores. So one processor can be produced using 14nm for critical layers and 22nm for less critical layers, but all the cores of that processor went to the same production process"

Frequency is not directly related to the manufacturing process so I will answer this question seperately. It is possible to use one multicore processor consisting of different cores with different clock speeds. This is currently happening in the mobile phone industry, where energy is also very important. Different cores can be clocked at different speeds (big little concept)

**2.**
Yes, I refer again to the big little concept. The processor consist of for example 5 cores, one which is very energy efficient, and 4 cores which can be turned on and off (or run at lower speed). In general, this smaller core has a different architecture then the other 4 cores.

Comment: So, we can 'print' CISC/RISC/ASIC through the same manufacturing process?

Comment: Yes, only the stucture of the components differs, it are all resistors, transistors and stuff. The nanometer number which you named tells us about the maximum amount of detail which can be displayed using a certain manufacturing technique. 14nm means that the smallest details are 14nm wide.

Comment: ARM's big.LITTLE (a trademarked name) is a special case of heterogeneous chip multiprocessor where the different cores effectively only differ in microarchitecture, i.e., even the operating system can treat them as the same except for performance/energy efficiency. NVIDIA's "companion core" concept is somewhat different from big.LITTLE in that it uses the same basic microarchitecture for the companion core but uses power-optimized transistors (a process supporting both kinds of transistors like TSMC's 40nm LPG process will tend to be more expensive).